# How to format Puppet for Chocolatey package with install arguments

Tags: visual-studio, puppet, chocolatey

I'm trying to replicate the following Chocolatey command line install in Puppet:

```
choco install visualstudio2013ultimate -InstallArguments "/Features:'WebTools SQL OfficeDeveloperTools LightSwitch'"
```

I've referred to the [documentation](https://github.com/chocolatey/puppet-chocolatey/issues/58) on using quotes in install arguments and have tried:

```
  package { 'visualstudio2013ultimate':
    ensure          => '12.0.21005.20141031', 
    install_options => ['-installArgs','"','/Features:', '""','WebTools SQL OfficeDeveloperTools LightSwitch','"""','"'],
  }
```

But this is failing to have the desired effect (it installs Visual Studio, then treats WebTools, SQL etc. as additional Chocolatey packages to install, not arguments to the Features switch).

Chocolatey log snippets:

```
2016-02-24 12:15:46,704 [DEBUG] - Command line: "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe" upgrade visualstudio2013ultimate -version 12.0.21005.20141031 -dvy -installArgs " /Features: "" "\"WebTools SQL OfficeDeveloperTools LightSwitch\"" """ "
2016-02-24 12:15:46,719 [DEBUG] - Received arguments: upgrade visualstudio2013ultimate -version 12.0.21005.20141031 -dvy -installArgs  

/Features: " "WebTools SQL OfficeDeveloperTools LightSwitch" " 
Version='12.0.21005.20141031'|AllVersions='False'|
SkipPackageInstallProvider='False'|
PackageNames='visualstudio2013ultimate;SQL;OfficeDeveloperTools;LightSwitch" ";'|
```

Can anyone advise how to correctly format the install_options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/chocolatey/chocolatey#install-options-with-spaces) for install options with the provider is very clear: every space must be covered with a separation. Puppet will automatically put quotes around a section with spaces, messing up the arguments. Splitting statements on every space keeps the spaces when Puppet reconstructs the arguments and keeps Puppet from messing with the resulting value passed to Chocolatey.

I also noticed that your documentation link points to a Github issue, not the resulting documentation. I realize the issue was the one about adding the documentation, but it wasn't quite correct in the issue notes. So it's probably better to refer to the resulting documentation that is most up to date. See https://forge.puppetlabs.com/chocolatey/chocolatey#install-options-with-spaces

Comment: Thanks `install_options => ['-installArgs','"', '/Features:\'WebTools', 'SQL', 'OfficeDeveloperTools', 'LightSwitch\'', '"']` appears to be working

Comment: It's a bit unintuitive at first, but it works and keeps away the auto quoting that Puppet does when there are spaces in the arguments

Comment: Whoa, that is *nasty*. Is there a Puppet issue filed to address this? Or is this considered appropriate?

Comment: It's considered appropriate Puppet behavior. Because normally if you have spaces you want the quoting.